# Syntax error: PHP brackets issue for IF and FOREACH?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, syntax-error, brackets

```
<?php if (count($errors) > 0): ?>
  <div class="error">
     <?php foreach ($errors as $error) ?>
     <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

My apologies if this is obvious to some of you more experienced PHP developers, but my code has the following errors;

> ForEach must uses braces
>
> Unexpected endforeach after string

I know that these `{` braces should inserted somewhere, but I'm not sure where and in what order? Also, what do I need to do after the string in question?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @adjan Thank you for pointing me towards that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using alternative syntax, you need to add a colon `:` after the `foreach`

```
foreach ($errors as $error):
                          ^^^
```

Alternatively, you can use brackets `{}` (which I *personally* find easier to read):

```
<?php foreach ($errors as $error) { ?>
     <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

And there's no reason to go in and out of PHP like that, you might as well do it all in one go, using double-quotes we can still pass variables by value, so we don't need to concat your HTML to the `$error` variable either.

```
<?php foreach ($errors as $error):
    echo "<p>$error</p>";
endforeach; ?>
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Thank your for your input. I'll look into the documentation. That's great.

Comment: Happy to help :-) *Cheers!*